# Can SimpleResolver accept multiple argument?

Tags: java, dns

I am using [SimpleResolver](http://www.dnsjava.org/dnsjava-current/org/xbill/DNS/SimpleResolver.java) from [dnsjava](http://www.dnsjava.org/) library to resolve my query in my code, so actually it is taking only one argument as a parameter like server name, but I want to pass multiple server names.

Is there any library which exist in Java so that I can pass multiple parameter like server name in one go? Or how can I extend the class to do the same?

Thanks

Comment: Please, post an example

Comment: example : SimpleResolver resolver = null;
            if (nameserver != null && !nameserver.isEmpty()) {
                resolver = new SimpleResolver(nameserver);
            }

Comment: so can we pass multiple arguments in SImple Resolver ?